# How to efficiently increase some elements of a Tensor with values specified by a SparseTensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

In my problem the tensors are 2D tensors, so basically I need some efficient ways to achieve

```
a_dense_matrix += a_sparse_matrix
```

I have found `tf.raw_ops.AssignAdd` and `tf.sparse.add`, but neither is suitable for me.

Comment: You're probably looking for [tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_add).

Comment: @Lescurel Tested `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add`, the function return an updated tensor, but left the original variable unchanged ？

Comment: Yes. Most operations in tensorflow avoid in place modifications. When running in graph mode, the graph will be optimized anyway.

Comment: @Lescurel I ran into performance issues (as expected), training time has increased about 5x :(